# show that Cov(X+ Y, X-Y)= Var(X) - Var(Y)

Tags: probability

I have up until Cov(X+Y,X-Y) = E[((X-E(X))+(Y-E(Y)))((X-E(X))-(Y+E(Y)))] and now I am stuck and do not know how this turns into Var(X)-Var(Y)

Comment: Expectation is linear, so, for example, $\mathbb{E}[X+Y] = \mathbb{E}[X] + \mathbb{E}[Y]$.

Comment: Yeah I know but first I would have to multiply the 4 different expressions through and then separate them and that is where it gets messy @Clarinetist

Comment: I am also unsure where the E(X^2)-E(X)^2 comes in since this is Var(X). I just don't see it

Comment: Your last $Y+E(Y)$ should actually be a $Y\color{blue}{-}E(Y)$. If you expand that, you should be able to factor the terms, notice a few perfect squares and get something in the form 

$$\text{E}\left[(X-\mu_X)^2 - (Y-\mu_Y)^2\right],$$
which is a difference of variances!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the bilinearity of covariance. We have 
$$\begin{align}\text{Cov}(X+Y,X-Y)&=\text{Cov}(X,X-Y)+\text{Cov}(Y,X-Y)\\
&=\text{Cov}(X,X)-\text{Cov}(X,Y)+\text{Cov}(Y,X)-\text{Cov}(Y,Y).\end{align}$$

**Remark:** We used an approach somewhat different from the one you suggested, because of its greater  smoothness. However, if you calculate 
$$E((X+Y)(X-Y))-E(X+Y)E(X-Y)$$
by expanding and using the linearity of expectation, things will turn out well.

Comment: so then would -Cov(X,Y)+Cov(Y,X) just cancel out? @AndreNicolas

Comment: Yes, $\text{Cov}(U,V)=\text{Cov}(V,U)$.

Comment: I redid it the way you mentioned it and it was way easier and cleaner. Thank you

Comment: You are welcome. The other way is more complicated, but not by much.